# How to use the sum of two aliases in an order by clause in postgres?

Tags: sql, postgresql

Here is what I have so far...

```
SELECT 
    *, 
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM upvote WHERE post_id = post.id) AS upvotes,
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM downvote WHERE post_id = post.id) AS downvotes
FROM 
    post
ORDER BY 
    upvotes DESC;
```

... but I would like to be able to `ORDER BY` the sum of `upvotes` and `downvotes`. Is this possible with Postgres? I am using version 12.

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.  Your code doesn't make much sense.

Comment: For correlated sub-queries with matching field names - use table aliases.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do it like this:

```
select * from (
SELECT *, 
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM upvote up WHERE up.post_id = post.id) AS upvotes,
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM downvote dw WHERE dw.post_id = post.id) AS downvotes
    FROM post) A
ORDER BY (upvotes+downvotes) DESC;
```

[Here is a small DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=1be52fb3152c5dbeaaaee07aaa02e4bd) for Postgresql 12.

Comment: Thanks, this worked great. What purpose does `A` make in this query?

Comment: You can use some more logic name instead of A(for example VOTES). It is an alias for the sub-query that you have to use. If it worked for you I would much appreciated if you accept it. Thanks for the up vote - from who ever it came from :)

Comment: It was me :) Stackoverflow prevents me from marking answers for a few minutes after the question is created. Should be all good now

Answer (score 0):

If you want the number of up and down votes for all posts (with votes), I would recommend:

```
select postid, sum(upvote) as upvotes, sum(downvote) as downvotes
from ((select post_id, 1 as upvote, 0 as downvote
       from upvotes
      ) union all
      (select post_id, 0, 1
       from downvotes
      )
     ) ud
group by postid;
```

You can add an `order by` clause to the end of the query:

```
order by count(*) desc
```